# Расположение файла, создаваемого библиотекой dll

Tags: c++, dll

В c++ коде моей библиотеки dll создается файл, в который записываются результаты. Как привязать этот файл к расположению dll? Сейчас он создается в папке проекта, с помощью которого я проверяю работу dll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924195/get-dll-path-at-runtime - пример без использования DllMain.

Comment: **Chorkov** и **Alex F** спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли! Всё получилось!